# publish only current cloud as octomap

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I want to do some comparisons between a global octomap and a local one, in order to detect new obstacles in the scene. For this, my proposed solution is to publish a stored octomap as global map and then with the input cloud from the sensor, obtain the local octomap and compare both of them. For this, I am launching two `octomap_server`s

My problem is that `octomap_server` keeps building an incremental map, and after a few scans the octomap will be too large to be traversed at high frequency. In this post (which is not very related actually) http://answers.ros.org/question/118871/create-an-occupancy-grid-map-from-octomap/ they suggest just to copy, paste and adapt code, but I wonder if there is a way to get ONLY the octomap from the last point cloud from the sensor.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209484/publish-only-current-cloud-as-octomap/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the local octomap you could try to use the reset service (http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server#Services) before inserting a new point cloud. This way you would have the desired behavior without any modifications to the code. Not sure if this runs fast enough though...

Cheers

Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-19**:
You mean to reset after every message is received?

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2015-05-19**:
Yes before or after receiving a new message

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-19**:
Ok I was able to do it and it more or less does what I want. I am not accepting the answer yet to see if somebody else have a better alternative. But thank you!